# Youtube enforces restricted mode after a short time after connecting

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, youtube

I have a networking problem about youtube.

When I first connect to my wireless network everything works fine. But after a few minutes youtube enforces restricted mode and I can't turn it off. It says "Restricted Mode is enabled by your network administrator". Other devices connected to the same wireless network doesn't have this problem (a few android devices and a windows machine).

Restarting network manager via "sudo service network-manager restart" temporarily solves the problem but after a while the problem respawns again.

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 17.04 . An older version of ubuntu (I think it was 14.04) didn't have this problem.

Perhaps these terminal command outputs may help you understand and solve my problem:

ifconfig

```
    enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:04:a6:d4:7f:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1103  bytes 115601 (115.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1103  bytes 115601 (115.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx940c6d8d7dc5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2ebb:e9e8:2e57:45f6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 94:0c:6d:8d:7d:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 208137  bytes 262002475 (262.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 104185  bytes 13767464 (13.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dig youtube.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> youtube.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2307
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;youtube.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
youtube.com.        128 IN  A   216.58.212.14

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 18 18:40:42 +03 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

All Network Manager settings are default. I deleted my connection settings and reconnected again to make sure but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a school computer? Or are you on a school network?

Comment: No, my own network and my personal computer. I don't have this problem while using another device/OS.

Comment: Are you using a age restricted google account therefore setting restricted mode?

Comment: Try reinstalling chrome.

Comment: I checked my account again, it isn't age restricted. Reinstalling didn't help. After that I tried other browsers but the problem persists. I think it's about [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6214622?hl=en) . HTTP Headers or DNS but I couldn't figure it out.